# javascript, test if nested attribute exists

Tags: javascript

```
var foo = a.foo or {}
var bar = foo.bar or {}
```

It is tedious to do this for every level of nesting.

Can I somehow do instead?

```
var bar = a.foo.bar or {}
```

Comment: No, not really, since otherwise you would get property bar doesn't exist on undefined, you could however make a function that checks this

Comment: You could do it with a small utility function as well (though I also believe Nina's code to be the easiest), like such: https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/85cbq9h1/

Answer (score 2):

You need a nested approach, you may have a look to [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

```
var bar = a && a.foo && a.foo.bar || {};
```

Comment: Won't this return false if `a` or `a.foo` is undefined.

Comment: Oh, javascript && operator does return full object, not the truth value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you need to use `||` to indicate for `or`.

```
var bar = a.foo.bar || {}; // However, a, a.foo may also be undefined
```

So, you need to check them using `&&` operator to know if they all are defined:

```
var bar = a && a.foo && a.foo.bar || {};
```